# Retrieve data from 2019 touch bar Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, data-recovery

Is there any way to retrieve data from an unresponsive 2019 touch bar Macbook Pro?

Since my 2019 Macbook pro died last week, I’ve found that

- Contemporary laptops solder hard drives directly onto boards, making data retrieval challenging.
- Apple approved service centers provide no service to retrive the data in the event of a logic board failure.
- For earlier MBP models with a hard drive soldered to the board, it was possible to use some sort of recovery tool produced by Apple that would be plugged directly into the broken board and accessed with Disk Utility on a working Mac.

Other info:
The computer suddenly died while working. I live in a country without any Apple store / genius bar. Apple approved service centers here have all just told me it is most likely a logic board failure (unwilling to investigate further) and that they don’t provide any sort of data retreival service. They are also unwilling to allow me to keep my current board after the fix unless I pay an extra fee of $750, claiming is Apple’s policy to ship the old logic board back to the US, and that I must pay to have it subsequently returned.

It seems there were [ways](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DmjOqeiedFc) to retrieve data on older Macbooks but I haven't found any solution for a 2019.

Comment: That video isn't retrieving data from a *failed* logic board, as far as I can tell. And of course, you need the special Apple 'box'.

If the logic board has failed, there's no guarantee that the disk controller (in the T2 chip) will work. The SSD storage itself is encrypted. 

I hate to say it, but: this is why backups are a thing. If you don't keep a second copy of your data on another device, then you can expect to lose it.

Comment: It’s possible to recover data, but it’s not DIY.  I recommend [Rossman Repair](https://rossmanngroup.com/) for this type of work

Comment: @Allan thanks. If they weren’t on the opposite side of the world I’d call them up :)